# Dafny "Call may violate context's modifies clause"

Tags: dafny

I'm attempting to verify a hashset but I've run into a problem with my insert method.

I don't understand why I'm getting the "call may violate context's modifies clause" error when I uncomment the inserts in main. I believe it to be something to do with the use of fresh, but I'm unclear on how / where to do this.

Code can be found at : https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/9UDG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that insert claims to modify `this` and `a`, which leaves open the possibility that the first call to `insert` changes the `a` field to point to something arbitrary, and then the second call to `insert` modifies that arbitrary thing.

A simple solution is to add `ensures a == old(a)` to `insert`.